# When I call one method webservice soap with string xml, and get error

Tags: xml, linux, web-services, soap

When I call one method webservice soap with string xml, and get error below:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:ServiceControllerwsdl">
    <x:Header/>
    <x:Body>
        <urn:luuPhieuNhap>
            <urn:xml_phieu_nhap><?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> 
<CustomerSearch>
    <AuthorID>$authorID</AuthorID>
    <UserID>$userID</UserID>
    <UserPassword>$userPassword</UserPassword>
    <Email>$customerEmail</Email>
</CustomerSearch></urn:xml_phieu_nhap>
            <urn:id_nhan_vien>297</urn:id_nhan_vien>
            <urn:id_kho>1</urn:id_kho>
        </urn:luuPhieuNhap>
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

And I got error below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Bad Request</faultstring>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But When I use text string , it not erro: below:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:ServiceControllerwsdl">
    <x:Header/>
    <x:Body>
        <urn:luuPhieuNhap>
            <urn:xml_phieu_nhap>fsdfdsfd</urn:xml_phieu_nhap>
            <urn:id_nhan_vien>297</urn:id_nhan_vien>
            <urn:id_kho>1</urn:id_kho>
        </urn:luuPhieuNhap>
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

I got good result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:ServiceControllerwsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:luuPhieuNhapResponse>
            <return xsi:type="xsd:integer">-1</return>
        </ns1:luuPhieuNhapResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How to fix it ? I use SOAP in linux , PHP7.0, yii framework 1.1.16.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape XML characters or change the schema to use `xsd:any`

See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2349082/6371459

> Unless the schema for the service describes exactly the XML you are trying to send, you have to use XML escapes to make your XML pass through the pipe as a string. <tag> instead of , etc, etc, etc.
>
> Or, you need to change the schema to use an XML schema any particle.

Also you can use CDATA (the text is not parsed) and re-parse the xml on server

```
 <urn:xml_phieu_nhap><![CDATA[xmlmessage]]></urn:xml_phieu_nhap>
```